# How to fix .locked already exists in nutch crawler?

Tags: nutch

I am a beginner user of nutch. When i was recrawling with bin/nutch crawl commands, I got an error of .locked already exists.

The following is my exception.
Link inversion

> /home/crawler_user/apache-nutch-1.14/bin/nutch invertlinks
>   /data/crawler_user/nutch/crawled-data/linkdb
>   /data/crawler_user/nutch/crawled-data/segments/20190423100709 LinkDb:
>   java.io.IOException: lock file
>   /data/crawler_user/nutch/crawled-data/linkdb/.locked already exists.
>   at org.apache.nutch.util.LockUtil.createLockFile(LockUtil.java:51) at
>   org.apache.nutch.crawl.LinkDb.invert(LinkDb.java:181) at
>   org.apache.nutch.crawl.LinkDb.run(LinkDb.java:337) at
>   org.apache.hadoop.util.ToolRunner.run(ToolRunner.java:70) at
>   org.apache.nutch.crawl.LinkDb.main(LinkDb.java:297)   Error running:
>   /home/crawler_user/apache-nutch-1.14/bin/nutch invertlinks
>   /data/crawler_user/nutch/crawled-data/linkdb
>   /data/crawler_user/nutch/crawled-data/segments/20190423100709 Failed
>   with exit value 255.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that you're not really running a different Nutch process at the same time (it is not really locked) then it should be safe to remove the `/data/crawler_user/nutch/crawled-data/linkdb/.locked` file. This usually means that the previous run of this stage (`invertlinks`) didn't complete successfully.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Actually, I accidentally detach a previous Nutch process running from the server. Then, I dump with "bin/nutch dump -segment" command. Then, while I re-crawl again, I stuck in here. 1) So, what should I do then? 2)I don't know how to check if dumping finish.

Comment: If nothing is really running at the moment, just delete the file `.locked` it should run normally again.

Comment: Here  is another error after re-crawling.I dump with a command 
"bin/nutch dump -segment <seg-path> -outputDir <output>". And then I got this error
log4j:ERROR Failed to flush writer, 
java.io.IOException: No space left on device
at java.io.FileOutputStream.writeBytes(Native Method)
at java.io.FileOutputStream.write(FileOutputStream.java:326)
at sun.nio.cs.StreamEncoder.writeBytes(StreamEncoder.java:221)
at sun.nio.cs.StreamEncoder.implFlushBuffer(StreamEncoder.java:291)
at sun.nio.cs.StreamEncoder.implFlush(StreamEncoder.java:295)
...

How should I solve it?

Comment: In this case the error it is related to the amount of free space in your disk: (from your logs) ```No space left on device```

Comment: Yes, but I run it on a server and there is no problem with storage. Do I need to change some configuration files?
     
Moreover, I got another error of 
"log4j:ERROR Failed to rename [/apache-nutch-1.14/logs/hadoop.log] to [/apache-nutch-1.14/logs/hadoop.log.2019-05-07]."
When checking log file, it stopped in the middle of writing.

Should I just stop the dumping process by killing the session and re-crawl it?

Comment: Thank you. I fixed it after removing unnecessary file from the partition I used.